# ROS2 Galactic - Python package not copied to Install folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, ros, ros2

I've developed a ROS2 node with Python, the code references an external Python package :

```
import readkeys
```

In order to allow the node to run, the package must be somewhere available, so I followed the recommendations form the doc :

https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/How-To-Guides/Using-Python-Packages.html#installing-via-a-virtual-environment

The virtual environment (venv) is setup with the package (readkey)

```
(venv) pip install readkeys
```

Problem: when running the node it returns invariably the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readkeys'
```

And indeed the readkeys package is not copied to the ROS2 workspace install folder, no chance for the  node to find the package...

Someone can help ?